# Custom Content Page

Tags: customization, templates

We've made a whole lot of templates for different types of blog posts. However, we also want to do fully custom 'power pages' that do not follow the WordPress theme we are using. These pages would be custom from top to bottom.

[Here is an example](http://cafecultureinsitu.com.au/blog/create-inspiring-workplace/) to illustrate my point:

The above is a normal blog post with the header, footer etc styled as per the blog.

However [this post on the same blog](http://cafecultureinsitu.com.au/blog/100-ways-reuse-pallets/) is totally custom
We would like to do the same thing as the second example. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I just can think two ways by now:

1) install another WordPress with other theme and create link to that

2) build these pages coding by yourself, php, HTML, CSS and Javascript

There is a third way, using functions of the wp core, like developing a plugin, but I'm still trying to develop one and don't understand very well to explain.

Comment: Hey Enrique,

That's what I want to do - option 2. Have someone build them custom and then just upload them. 

How do I do this? Where do I upload the page once it is finished?

Comment: TheGreatestGoat, you have your WordPress installation in a host, don't you? If yes, you need to put your built page by coding anywhere inside the installation. You just need to get the url to the page location and create a link in WordPress site

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to simply install another theme that matches the different design you require, and activate for those pages only that need it using this plugin:

[Multiple Themes Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering because the comment would be very big. Suppose your installation is in www.host.com.
So you have www.host.com/wp-content, www.host.com/wp-admin and so on. You can put the built page by coding at the root of WordPress. To access it you need a link to the url www.host.com/codedpage.html (or. Php, or whatever). But if you prefer you can create a new directory, let's name it as mydir, and then you have this valid url www.host.com/mydir. You can put codedpage.html inside this new directory and your link need to be www.host.com/mydir/codedpage.html.

Indeed, if you create a directory, you can call your coded page as index.